# Flask: importing custom functions into API

Tags: python, python-import

I come from a background in R and I'm trying to develop an API in Python using Flask. My folder looks something like this:

```
project
--server.py
--custom_functions
----func1.py
----func2.py
--more_custom_functions
----subfolder1
------func3.py
------func4.py
----subfolder2
------func5.py
------func6.py
```

I prefer to organise my custom functions into different subfolders based on their purpose, so custom_functions could be for instance functions related to cleaning, et cetera. Ideally, when I launch server.py using (in Windows CMD, if it helps)

```
python server.py
```

in the directory /project, I'd like to be able to import every function. A function looks like

```
import numpy as np 
def func1 (x) : 
     return(x + 1)
```

and nothing else.

My question is this: how does one at initialisation of the server (i.e. upon `python server.py`) import every single module (e.g. *numpy*/*pandas*) globally so that all the subfunctions can use these modules without having a call to import inside them, i.e. (in the above example, can we remove `import numpy as np`), and import all the functions `func1`, `func2`, ..., `func6`? I don't mind if I have to call them as `custom_functions.func1` or `more_custom_functions.subfolder1.func3`, say, if necessary.

I've tried a number of things such as putting `__init__.py` in some of the folders and adding `__all__ = ["func1", "func2"]` into this file (as well as leaving it empty). I've also tried

```
import sys, os
sys.path.append(os.getcwd() + '\\custom_functions') 
import custom_functions
```

and variations of this like from custom_functions import *, all to no avail.

Some of the errors I get involve:

`module 'custom_functions' has no attribute func1`, or
`name 'custom_functions' is not defined`.

In R, I would use something along the lines of `source(dir, recursive=TRUE, pattern="*.R")` and then library/require all the packages at the very start of the code and all is good. Is there an easy equivalent? Or do I have to move every function into a single file (say *functions.py*) and then import functions?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that there is an intermediate solution that more or less suits my needs, even if it might not be best practice when it comes to Python.

```
import os
import glob
files_names = glob.glob(os.getcwd() + '\custom_functions\**\*.py')
for f in file_names : exec(open(f).read())
```

This allows me to use the custom functions without needing to call them as modules, i.e. I can use them like

```
func1()
```

instead of

```
custom_functions.func1()
```